# PPTx with embedded video play on iOS

Tags: ios, video, ios7, powerpoint

I am making an application which should be able to play any videos embedded in a PPTx. Currently using [Quicklook Framework for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/filemanagement/conceptual/documentinteraction_topicsforios/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html) I am able to see the text or any images but not able to play the video. 
 I thought of one solution as,
 Converting the PPTx to zip and then parse the XML files to give the video and then play, which doesn't look very practical as it needs to be done for every file where the structure keeps changing with very slide/PPT 
 
 [Slideshark](https://www.slideshark.com/) is able to play videos embedded in a PPT. 
 
 Any Ideas on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Converting PPTs into HTML5 is one of the solution.

Comment: The app is such that the user can download PPT and then view the same, is there a way that the app can convert the PPT to HTML5 via an API ? [Crocodoc](https://developers.box.com/view-api/) looks like an option

Comment: Converting PPT into HTML5 in phone will be heavy process. I will suggest that it will be better if conversion happens at server side.

Comment: Yes makes sense. I have just tried the [Box View Platform](http://developers.box.com/view/) still not able to play the video. Wonder if there are any limitations on the format of the video